Streaming a tty docker container
I need to implement the functionality of streaming the docker terminal of a container, for this I used ContainerLogs and collected logs from the container line by line.
However, when the container uses a tty, I have problems. In this case, I get log lines with escape codes (terminal clear, lines, etc.). I have no problem displaying this in a normal form, but it’s difficult to call it streaming a container terminal with a tty.
You can connect to the container terminal without using docker-api using docker attach, but it’s also not clear to me how to stream it later
I would like to somehow stream a kind of “terminal screen” of a container, a matrix of symbols, but I can’t find information on this anywhere.

This may need some clarification. A docker container itself has no terminal afaik. You rather have your own terminal (bash, zsh or whatever) running on your machine and connect via docker exec -it ... to sh or bash or zsh - whatever runs inside your container. At this point you are inside the container and able to perform any commands you'd like. Is it from this point on where you want to stream the terminal session?

When you like docker attach, you should use Client.ContainerAttach, that's what it is using. ContainerLogs uses the json-file or journald logging driver optionally trailing output, introducing more buffering, while ContainerAttach uses stdin, stdout and stderr.
